# Numerical combinations without overlap - lack of a better name for it

Tags: algorithm, math, combinations, overlap

## Information

Let's say I have all possible combinations of rows where values can be 0, 1 or 2. E.G:

```
00000
```

From all these, I want to select the rows which allow no overlap of rows if I perform the following:

Starting with the first row **00000**, we select all rows with a difference of **1** number, the rows we get in this case is:

```
00001
00002
00010
00020
00100
00200
01000
02000
10000
20000
```

With this, these rows, including 00000 are now *excluded*

The next row after 00000 would be **00001**, but since this is already found above, that is **invalid**.

## Invalid

If we jump further forward to **00011** we get the following rows:

```
00010 // This is already found in the above, so 00011 is invalid
00012
00001
00021
00111
00211
01011
02011
10011
20011
```

## Valid

If we jump further ahead to 00111:

```
00110
00112
00101
00121
00011
00211
01111
02111
10111
20111
```

## List

None of the above are found previously, now we have a list of:

```
00000
00001
00002
00010
00020
00100
00200
01000
02000
10000
20000
00111
00110
00112
00101
00121
00011
00211
01111
02111
10111
20111
```

## Moving on

Lets assume we are now on row **22111**, with the above process we get:

```
22110
22112
22101
22121
22011
22211
20111 // This is already in the above list
21111
02111 // This too, so row 22111 is invalid
12111
```

## In conclusion

I only selected these above rows at random, what I'm after is a way of figuring out all valid rows (in accordance with the above process) without having to iterate through each row in the complete list.

Thanks for any insight provided!

Comment: I do not follow ... you want to have all combinations of a 16 digit number with base=3 (digits 0,1,2) ? What do you mean with overlap? if you want that the numbers have only distinct digits except zero that is called in English combinations without repetitions I think. So which one is it? your example is not very clear try to add example of valid numbers and invalid also with description why are they invalid

Comment: not sure of what you want. give a concrete example please

Comment: @Whitefret It's pretty clear from the examples and attempted solution that  it's a question about combinatorics. In this case, Mathias doesn't seem to have encountered the mathematical discipline yet and attempted his own (offbeat) solution.

Comment: I'm sorry if it was completely unclear, I have updated the question with a more clear cut example, I think!

Comment: Oh, I see, so you want to avoid repeating a substring in the solution? So `1111` would not be valid if `1`, `11`, or `111` had already been generated? If the generated list is predictable (always occurs in the same pattern), you can simplify everything with math. If it is random, then you need to use an efficient data structure, like a map or array, to keep track of what's been generated, then compare it to the current one. My bet is that you can simplify the problem with combinations with repetition.

Comment: No, not a substring, but let's call it a subrow. 10111 would not be valid if for example 10112 is already found (even if 10111 is not). Like, if a subrow is invalid, the entire row would be invalid.

Comment: So in that sense, you're generating in reverse order. The mathematics allows for this. The [link in my answer](https://www.mathsisfun.com/combinatorics/combinations-permutations.html) has a good solution for your problem at the bottom; essentially turning the 'combination with repetition' into a permutation. Consider telling us in your question *why* you're making this program. We may be able to point you to a simpler method than trying to make this confusing list.

Comment: I must say I don't quite get how that is useful in my case :( I do however feel that generating in the reverse order is a good way to describe it and thanks for the link!